# Using dropbox-api-content-hasher without node

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, phonegap

I have used dropbox-api-content-hasher ([gitrepo here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-api-content-hasher)) within a node.js environment for an Electron project with great success, but now I need to use it in a Phonegap/cordova project and I've no idea how to replace the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dch = require('dropbox-content-hasher');
```

... with vanilla javascript so I can use it!

I have included the `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropbox-content-hasher.js"></script>` but I need to access the `dch` variable to do the following:

```
const hasher = dch.create();
```

and then access `hasher` the rest of what I need to do. I don't have the experience on how to convert it across, any ideas?

I am building in phonegap rather than cordova cli as I'm more experienced in this approach.

**EDIT:**

This is a fiddle of my attempt based on Alex's answer but I'm getting 'CryptoJS is not a constructor' in the web console. I don't know how to bring in the cryptojs library!

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/littleninja/Lttm2jhc/)

Answer (score 0):

I just needed the same and adapted the example from the [dropbox repo](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-api-content-hasher/tree/master/js-node).
I use the [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/) library. The code is in ES6 and is used in a [quasar-framework](http://quasar-framework.org/) app (which btw. might be interesting for you, due to phonegap/cordova):

```
/**
 * Computes a hash using the same algorithm that the Dropbox API uses for the
* the "content_hash" metadata field.
*
* The `digest()` method returns a hexadecimal-encoded version
* of the digest of the hash.
* The "content_hash" field in the Dropbox API is a hexadecimal-encoded version
* of the digest.
*
* Example:
*
*     import DropboxContentHasher from 'dropboxContentHasher'
*
*     let hasher = new DropboxContentHasher()
*     hasher.update(content) // content is some string or CryptoJS.lib.WordArray
*     return hasher.digest()
*/

import cryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

const BLOCK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024

class DropboxContentHasher {
  constructor () {
    this._overallHasher = cryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create()
    this._blockHasher = cryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create()
    this._blockPos = 0
  }

  update (data) {
    let offset = 0
    while (offset < data.length) {
      if (this._blockPos === BLOCK_SIZE) {
        this._overallHasher.update(this._blockHasher.finalize())
        this._blockHasher = cryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create()
        this._blockPos = 0
      }
      let spaceInBlock = BLOCK_SIZE - this._blockPos
      let inputPartEnd = Math.min(data.length, offset + spaceInBlock)
      let inputPartLength = inputPartEnd - offset
      this._blockHasher.update(data.slice(offset, inputPartEnd))
      this._blockPos += inputPartLength
      offset = inputPartEnd
    }
  }

  digest () {
    if (this._blockPos > 0) {
      this._overallHasher.update(this._blockHasher.finalize())
      this._blockHasher = null
    }
    let r = this._overallHasher.finalize().toString()
    this._overallHasher = null // Make sure we can't use this object anymore.
    return r
  }
}

export default DropboxContentHasher
```

Comment: I'm not using any framework so I can't use `import`... how do I literally get this to stand on it's own?

Comment: You can include the crypto-js via a script tag (just download the src from their webpage) and convert the above code to simple javascript functions. The instance variables could be global vars. Beside the import and class statements, there is nothing ES6 specific, so it should be straightforward.

Comment: Hi again, I know this is lame but I still can't get this to work and I really need it! Could you possibly show me how you would convert it to 'simple javascript functions' please? And which file from the list here [Git src folder](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/tree/develop/src) I should be including? I am just not there with my understanding to do it!! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple JavaScript implementation using `crypto-js`:

```
function computeContentHash(content) {
  const BLOCK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
  let hash = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
  for (let p = 0; p < content.length; p += BLOCK_SIZE) {
    let chunk = content.substr(p, BLOCK_SIZE);
    hash.update(CryptoJS.SHA256(chunk));
  }
  return hash.finalize().toString();
}
```